# How do I use the Google Civic Information API to retrieve members of Congress for a given location?

Tags: api, google-api, lookup

I've tried using the civicinfo.representatives.representativeInfoByAddress endpoint in the API explorer (https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/civicinfo/v2/civicinfo.representatives.representativeInfoByAddress).

**Here's my problem:  That endpoint returns all state, federal, and local offices EXCEPT the U.S. House of Representatives!**  I can see the governor, senators, state senators, but NOT members of Congress.  I can't find anything in the documentation to explain why this blatantly important data is being omitted, nor can I find any alternative sources (that are actually current) for this data.

Why is Google withholding the Congressional data and how do I get it?  That's the ONE THING I need from this API and it seems to be missing from the results.  I've tried playing with the parameters and whatnot but I can't find that data.

There has to be a way to find this information.  In the Google API Explorer (see above link), try entering "WA" for the "address" field and leave everything else blank (setting the next one to TRUE makes no difference and the others are just filters).  Here's the data that's returned:

```
{
 "kind": "civicinfo#representativeInfoResponse",
 "normalizedInput": {
  "line1": "",
  "city": "",
  "state": "WA",
  "zip": ""
 },
 "divisions": {
  "ocd-division/country:us": {
   "name": "United States",
   "officeIndices": [
    0,
    1
   ]
  },
  "ocd-division/country:us/state:wa": {
   "name": "Washington",
   "officeIndices": [
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    6,
    7,
    8,
    9,
    10,
    11
   ]
  }
 },
 "offices": [
  {
   "name": "President of the United States",
   "divisionId": "ocd-division/country:us",
   "levels": [
    "country"
   ],
   "roles": [
    "headOfState",
    "headOfGovernment"
   ],
   "officialIndices": [
    0
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Vice-President of the United States",
   "divisionId": "ocd-division/country:us",
   "levels": [
    "country"
   ],
   "roles": [
    "deputyHeadOfGovernment"
   ],
   "officialIndices": [
    1
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "United States Senate",
   "divisionId": "ocd-division/country:us/state:wa",
   "levels": [
    "country"
   ],
   "roles": [
    "legislatorUpperBody"
   ],
   "officialIndices": [
    2,
    3
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Governor",
   "divisionId": "ocd-division/country:us/state:wa",
   "levels": [
    "administrativeArea1"
   ],
   "roles": [
    "headOfGovernment"
   ],
   "officialIndices": [
    4
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Lieutenant Governor",
   "divisionId": "ocd-division/country:us/state:wa",
   "levels": [
    "administrativeArea1"
   ],
   "roles": [
    "deputyHeadOfGovernment"
   ],
   "officialIndices": [
    5
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "State Auditor",
   "divisionId": "ocd-division/country:us/state:wa",
   "officialIndices": [
    6
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "State Treasurer",
   "divisionId": "ocd-division/country:us/state:wa",
   "officialIndices": [
    7
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Attorney General",
   "divisionId": "ocd-division/country:us/state:wa",
   "officialIndices": [
    8
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Secretary of State",
   "divisionId": "ocd-division/country:us/state:wa",
   "officialIndices": [
    9
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Insurance Commissioner",
   "divisionId": "ocd-division/country:us/state:wa",
   "officialIndices": [
    10
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Commissioner of Public Lands",
   "divisionId": "ocd-division/country:us/state:wa",
   "officialIndices": [
    11
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "State Superintendent of Public Instruction",
   "divisionId": "ocd-division/country:us/state:wa",
   "officialIndices": [
    12
   ]
  }
 ],
 "officials": [
  {
   "name": "Donald J. Trump",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "The White House",
     "line2": "1600 Pennsylvania Avenue NW",
     "city": "Washington",
     "state": "DC",
     "zip": "20500"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Republican",
   "phones": [
    "(202) 456-1111"
   ],
   "urls": [
    "http://www.whitehouse.gov/"
   ],
   "photoUrl": "https://www.whitehouse.gov/sites/whitehouse.gov/files/images/45/PE%20Color.jpg",
   "channels": [
    {
     "type": "GooglePlus",
     "id": "+whitehouse"
    },
    {
     "type": "Facebook",
     "id": "whitehouse"
    },
    {
     "type": "Twitter",
     "id": "potus"
    },
    {
     "type": "YouTube",
     "id": "whitehouse"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Mike Pence",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "The White House",
     "line2": "1600 Pennsylvania Avenue NW",
     "city": "Washington",
     "state": "DC",
     "zip": "20500"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Republican",
   "phones": [
    "(202) 456-1111"
   ],
   "urls": [
    "http://www.whitehouse.gov/"
   ],
   "photoUrl": "https://www.whitehouse.gov/sites/whitehouse.gov/files/images/45/VPE%20Color.jpg",
   "channels": [
    {
     "type": "GooglePlus",
     "id": "+whitehouse"
    },
    {
     "type": "Facebook",
     "id": "whitehouse"
    },
    {
     "type": "Twitter",
     "id": "VP"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Maria Cantwell",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "511 Hart Senate Office Building",
     "city": "Washington",
     "state": "DC",
     "zip": "20510"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Democratic",
   "phones": [
    "(202) 224-3441"
   ],
   "urls": [
    "https://www.cantwell.senate.gov/"
   ],
   "photoUrl": "http://bioguide.congress.gov/bioguide/photo/C/C000127.jpg",
   "channels": [
    {
     "type": "Facebook",
     "id": "senatorcantwell"
    },
    {
     "type": "Twitter",
     "id": "senatorcantwell"
    },
    {
     "type": "YouTube",
     "id": "SenatorCantwell"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Patty Murray",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "154 Russell Senate Office Building",
     "city": "Washington",
     "state": "DC",
     "zip": "20510"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Democratic",
   "phones": [
    "(202) 224-2621"
   ],
   "urls": [
    "http://www.murray.senate.gov/public/"
   ],
   "photoUrl": "http://bioguide.congress.gov/bioguide/photo/M/M001111.jpg",
   "channels": [
    {
     "type": "GooglePlus",
     "id": "+pattymurray"
    },
    {
     "type": "Twitter",
     "id": "pattymurray"
    },
    {
     "type": "YouTube",
     "id": "SenatorPattyMurray"
    },
    {
     "type": "Facebook",
     "id": "pattymurray"
    },
    {
     "type": "YouTube",
     "id": "pattymurray"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Jay Inslee",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "PO Box 40002",
     "city": "Olympia",
     "state": "WA",
     "zip": "98504"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Democratic",
   "phones": [
    "(360) 902-4111"
   ],
   "urls": [
    "http://www.governor.wa.gov/"
   ],
   "photoUrl": "http://www.governor.wa.gov/sites/default/files/images/720px-for-web_0.jpg",
   "emails": [
    "Governor.JayInslee@governor.wa.gov"
   ],
   "channels": [
    {
     "type": "Facebook",
     "id": "WaStateGov"
    },
    {
     "type": "Twitter",
     "id": "GovInslee"
    },
    {
     "type": "YouTube",
     "id": "UCJhWBqWVdVnPro7tx2t7j3w"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Cyrus Habib",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "PO Box 40400",
     "city": "Olympia",
     "state": "WA",
     "zip": "98504"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Democratic",
   "phones": [
    "(360) 786-7700"
   ],
   "urls": [
    "http://www.ltgov.wa.gov/"
   ],
   "photoUrl": "http://www.ltgov.wa.gov/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Senator-Habib-2015_CROPPED-225x300.jpg",
   "emails": [
    "ltgov@ltgov.wa.gov"
   ],
   "channels": [
    {
     "type": "Twitter",
     "id": "waltgov"
    },
    {
     "type": "Facebook",
     "id": "Lt-Governor-Cyrus-Habib-347384975292728"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Pat (Patrice) McCarthy",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "Insurance Building Capitol Campus",
     "line2": "302 Sid Snyder Avenue SW",
     "city": "Olympia",
     "state": "WA",
     "zip": "98504"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Democratic",
   "phones": [
    "(360) 902-0370"
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Duane Davidson",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "PO Box 40200",
     "city": "Olympia",
     "state": "WA",
     "zip": "98504"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Republican",
   "phones": [
    "(360) 902-9001"
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Bob Ferguson",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "PO Box 40100",
     "city": "Olympia",
     "state": "WA",
     "zip": "98504"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Democratic",
   "phones": [
    "(360) 753-6200"
   ],
   "urls": [
    "http://www.atg.wa.gov/"
   ],
   "channels": [
    {
     "type": "Facebook",
     "id": "WAStateAttorneyGeneral"
    },
    {
     "type": "Twitter",
     "id": "AGOWA"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Kim Wyman",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "PO Box 40220",
     "city": "Olympia",
     "state": "WA",
     "zip": "98504"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Republican",
   "phones": [
    "(360) 902-4151"
   ],
   "urls": [
    "http://www.sos.wa.gov/"
   ],
   "emails": [
    "kim.wyman@sos.wa.gov"
   ],
   "channels": [
    {
     "type": "Facebook",
     "id": "WaSecretaryOfState"
    },
    {
     "type": "Twitter",
     "id": "secstatewa"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Mike Kreidler",
   "party": "Democratic",
   "phones": [
    "(360) 725-7000"
   ],
   "urls": [
    "http://www.insurance.wa.gov/"
   ],
   "channels": [
    {
     "type": "Facebook",
     "id": "wsoic"
    },
    {
     "type": "Twitter",
     "id": "WAinsuranceblog"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Hilary Franz",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "PO Box 47000",
     "city": "Olympia",
     "state": "WA",
     "zip": "98504"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Democratic",
   "phones": [
    "(360) 902-1000"
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Chris Reykdal",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "Mail stop: 47200 Old Capitol Building P.O. Box 47200",
     "city": "Olympia",
     "state": "WA",
     "zip": "98504"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Nonpartisan",
   "phones": [
    "(360) 725-6115"
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

Now, do a text search for "Adam Smith" in that JSON.  He's a current member of Congress in WA.  You'll notice that string is not present, nor are any other members of Congress, nor can I find any reference links in the return to look them up.

What am I missing??  It seems utterly insane to me that everything is included there *except* members of the U.S. House (but federal and state Senates are included).  That means it's possible that the data is available somehow but I'm just not figuring it out.  Can anybody help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is a couple of months late but you need to specify the to look for the roles `legislatorUpperBody` and `legislatorLowerBody`.

If you just want to have these two peices of infomation try running the query

`https://www.googleapis.com/civicinfo/v2/representatives?address=[address]&levels=country&roles=legislatorUpperBody&roles=legislatorLowerBody&key=[api_key]`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning all possible results for representatives for a given area, the API seems to only return exact matches.

Assuming 2 requests that both use `levels=country&roles=legislatorLowerBody`.

I get 0 results using the address `Boston, MA`.

I get the proper representative using the address `10 Summer St, Boston, MA`.

Congressional districts can be pretty specific. In some cases the street number along the same street will dictate one district versus another.